# pgflayeron not working with \onlayer

Tags: tikz-pgf

Below is a MWE (well, not working, but ...) where my objective is to get a number of bullet points revealed one by one at the end of which I want to have the block that is superimposed on the itemized text. I can't get it to work and would appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Open problems}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Open problem 1
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Bullet 1
        \item Bullet 2
    \end{itemize}

    \item<2-> Open problem 2
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Bullet 1
        \item Bullet 2
    \end{itemize}

    \item<3-> Open problem 3
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Bullet 1
    \item Bullet 2
    \end{itemize}

    \item<4-> Open problem 4
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Bullet 1
    \item Bullet 2
    \end{itemize}

    \item<5-> Open problem 5
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Bullet 1
    \item Bullet 2
    \end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

\onslide<6>{
    \vspace{-3cm}

    \pgfdeclarelayer{fg}
    \pgfsetlayers{fg,main}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{fg}
        \onslide<6>{
            \begin{block}{This is most important}
                Whatever
            \end{block}
        }
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You do not need layers for that. If you add the block last, it will be on top of the other stuff automatically.

Comment: Noted, thanks. I'll try it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beamer allows you to automatically delay each `\item` without having to do it manually as you did. Just use the `[<+->]` option: `\begin{itemize}[<+->]`
But so that the sub-lists are not delayed, it is enough to place the option `[<.->]` on each of them: `\begin{itemize}[<.->]`

To display the `block`, it is also unnecessary to delay manually, the blocks have this option natively: `\begin{block}<6->{This is most important}`

I commented on unnecessary lines without deleting them.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Open problems}

  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Open problem 1
    \begin{itemize}[<.->]
        \item Bullet 1
        \item Bullet 2
    \end{itemize}

    \item Open problem 2
    \begin{itemize}[<.->]
        \item Bullet 1
        \item Bullet 2
    \end{itemize}

    \item Open problem 3
    \begin{itemize}[<.->]
    \item Bullet 1
    \item Bullet 2
    \end{itemize}

    \item Open problem 4
    \begin{itemize}[<.->]
    \item Bullet 1
    \item Bullet 2
    \end{itemize}

    \item Open problem 5
    \begin{itemize}[<.->]
    \item Bullet 1
    \item Bullet 2
    \end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

%\onslide<6>{
    \vspace{-3cm}

%    \pgfdeclarelayer{fg}
%    \pgfsetlayers{fg,main}
%    \begin{pgfonlayer}{fg}
%    \onslide<6>{
            \begin{block}<6->{This is most important}
                Whatever
            \end{block}
%    }
%    \end{pgfonlayer}
%}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```